# Sizing and resolution

Tags: css, resolution, mobile-application, sizing

Just wondering what are different in this sizes or resolutions

**960dp x 720dp**

**960em x 720em**

**960px x 720px**

And in comparing with **%**

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#lengths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing the link from Mr Lister ('http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#lengths') you only have to know that % meanst he % of the parent's element width/height